# Copying Production Recycle bin data to Sandbox without undelete in Prod

Tags: sandbox, recycle-bin

Is there a way to copy recycle bin from production to a fullcopy sandbox?

Does refreshing a sandbox copies the recycle bin data as well to the sandbox? If not out of the box, then is there a way to do so?

Comment: I believe it does, but I don't have a full sandbox refresh available to test it out on.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox. Let me refresh it and discover then. It would great if you could throw me a link or blog mentioning same in case you come across one.

Comment: I refreshed a fullcopy sandbox and it did not copy the recycle bin from production.

Comment: Good to know. You should formally answer the question properly (I see you deleted your prior answer: it just needs some work).

Comment: @sfdcfox I posted that as ans so that some one coming across can notice it easily. I did not found any work around to add on to the answer. If anything I am missing, please let me know so that I do not disturb the hygiene of this forum. :)